# Finite distributive lattices as lattice of ideals of a finite ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lattice-theory, ideals

Is there a finite distributive lattice that is *not* isomorphic to the lattice of ideals of a finite ring?

Comment: Do you consider the lattice of (1) right ideals, (2) two-sided ideals of a possibly non-commutative ring, or the lattice of (3) ideals of a commutative ring? Do rings have an identity element?

Comment: There are however results that imply that a finite distributive lattice is isomorphic to the lattice of ideals of a ring (not necessarily finite). See for example https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927878008822518

Comment: Ideal generally means two-sided ideal. Since finite rings are artinian and Morita equivalent rings have isomorphic lattices of ideals you can assume the quotient by the radical is commutative (as finite division algebras are commutative)

Comment: I suspect there are results on congruence distributive varieties that can help here.  You might ask William DeMo or Keith Kearnes directly, as I have not looked at the relevant literature in over a decade.  Gerhard "Time Flies When Jumping Primes" Paseman, 2018.02.27.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg It may be obvious, but I fail to prove your claim regarding the reduction to a commutative quotient. If $R$ is a finite ring, I understand that $R/J(R)$ is Morita equivalent to a product of finite fields (Artin-Wedderburn) and hence commutative. But how to produce a finite ring $S$ which is Morita equivalent to $R$ and such that $S/J(S)$ is commutative?

Comment: @LucGuyot, it is a standard fact that any Artinian ring R is Morita equivalent to a basic Artinian ring.  An Artinian ring R is basic if $R/J(R)$ is a direct product of fields.  The way you do this is let $P_1,\ldots, P_s$ be a complete list of non-isomorphic projective indecomposable modules and Let $P=P_1\oplus \cdots \oplus P_S$. Then $P$ is a projective generator so $End(P)$ is Morita equivalent to $R$.  It is not difficult to check that $End(P)$ is basic. You can find this in standard books on Artin algebras like Auslander et al.

Comment: Dominic, this is a frustrating thread because you have failed to respond to the questions/issues addressed to you in the comment thread under the question. In addition, you have accepted an answer where is it unclear (in view of discussion by Keith Kearnes) that it really answered the intended question.

Comment: In fact ideal lattices are seldom distributive, it is the lattice of *radical* ideals that is always distributive. So another interesting question is whether a finite distributive lattice is the lattice of radical ideals of a finite ring; I believe the answer is yes.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit sloppy! - I was thinking about commutative rings (i.e., both operations are commutative).

Comment: But since @LucGuyot has put in a lot of effort, I thought it might be better to clarify this in *another* question. I feel it's unfair to Luc to unaccept the answer just because I was imprecise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **yes**, there is a finite distributive lattice which is not isomorphic to the lattice

- of right ideals in a non-commutative ring with identity,
- of ideals in a commutative ring with identity.

Let $L = \left\{ \{0, 1, 2\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \emptyset
\right\}$ be partially ordered by inclusion (the [Hasse
diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) is a *diamond with
a tail*). Then $L$ is a [distributive
lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) with join the
union of subsets and meet the intersection of subsets.

*Rings are supposed unital, but not necessarily commutative.*

> > **Claim 1**. The lattice $L$ is not isomorphic to the lattice of
> >     right ideals of a finite ring.

I will make implicit use of well-known facts regarding finite rings with
identity, see e.g., Chapter I of Richard Wirt's PhD thesis, ["Finite
non-commutative local
rings"](https://shareok.org/bitstream/handle/11244/3379/7229919.PDF?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).

> > *Proof of Claim 1.* Let $R$ be a finite ring whose lattice of right
> >     ideals is isomorphic to $L$. Then $R$ is a local ring whose radical
> >     $\mathfrak{m}$ is the direct sum of two minimal right ideals
> >     $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$. As $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{m}$ is
> >     either null or equal to $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{m}$ is nilpotent,
> >     we deduce that $\mathfrak{a} \mathfrak{m} = 0$. Likewise, $\mathfrak{b}
> > \mathfrak{m} = 0$. As a result, $\mathfrak{m}^2 = 0$. Therefore
> >     $\mathfrak{m}$ is a vector space of dimension at least $2$ over $K =
> > R/\mathfrak{m}$. Hence $\mathfrak{m}$ contains at least a third
> >     non-zero $K$-subspace, a contradiction.

In the commutative setting, the same example is valid without further
finiteness assumption.

> > **Claim 2**. The lattice $L$ is not isomorphic to the ideal lattice
> >     of a commutative ring with identity.
> >
> > *Proof of Claim 2.* The ideal lattice of a commutative ring $R$ with
> >     identity is distributive if and only if $R$ is
> >     [arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_ring), i.e., if
> >     the localization $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ of $R$ at $\mathfrak{m}$ is a
> >     [uniserial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_module) for every
> >     maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$. If $R$ is a commutative ring with
> >     identity whose ideal lattice is $L$, then $R$ is
> >     [local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring), but not uniserial, a
> >     contradiction.

**Addendum.** As observed by Keith Kearnes in the comments below, the lattice $L$ is isomorphic to the lattice of two-sided ideals in a finite non-commutative ring.

Comment: But did OP say 'commutative'?

Comment: @ToddTrimble No, he certainly didn't and I shamefully missed that point, thanks. I have now extended my answer.

Comment: @LucGuyot: In fact, L **IS** the ideal lattice of a finite ring. Let $K$ be a finite field that is a quadratic extension of its prime field. Let $R$ be the ring of all $2\times 2$ matrices $\begin{bmatrix} a&m\\0&a\end{bmatrix}$ where $a\in K$, $m\in K\otimes_{\mathbb Z} K$, left/right actions of $K$ on $K\otimes_{\mathbb Z} K$ are determined by $r(p\otimes q)=rp\otimes q$ and $(p\otimes q)r=p\otimes qr$.

Comment: @KeithKearnes Many thanks for your feedback. I am willing to correct or to remove the faulty parts. But I need to digest your two comments first.

Comment: @LucGuyot: The problem is that if K is an arbitrary field, then Mn(K) ⊗Z Mn(K)^op need not be a matrix ring over a field. This fails already when n=1.

Comment: @KeithKearnes I can't but acknowledge this mistake, thanks again for pointing it out. About your example, isn't the Jacobson radical both a maximal and minimal two-sided ideal?

Comment: @LucGuyot: "isn't the Jacobson radical both a maximal and minimal two-sided ideal?"  It is maximal, but not minimal. I took $K$ to be a quadratic extension of its prime field so that the $(K,K)$-bimodule $K\otimes_Z K$  would not be simple, hence the radical of the ring would not be minimal.

Comment: @KeithKearnes Great, I got it. I have removed the faulty claim.